# Model returns null in joined view model

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I created a view model to pass Programs list to checkboxlist and model class to view but I am not sure why my model class in joined view model returns null in the post method. Below is my code:
Models:

```
    public class clsPrograms
    {
            public string ProgramValue { get; set; }
            public string ProgramText { get; set; }
            [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.NotMapped]
            public bool Selected { get; set; }
       
    }

public class Letter{
  [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public clsPrograms Programs { get; set; }
}
```

CreateController:

```
public IActionResult Create()
    {
      
        List<clsPrograms> programsList = new List<clsPrograms>();
        programsList.Add(new clsPrograms { ProgramValue = "Program A", ProgramText = "Program A", Selected = false });
        programsList.Add(new clsPrograms { ProgramValue = "Program B", ProgramText = "Program B", Selected = false });
        var viewModel = new viewModel
        {
            Letter = new Letter(),
            Programs = programsList
        };
        viewModel.Letter.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
        return View(viewModel);
    }
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
     public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Id,Programs")] viewModel model)    
    {

        //for debug modelstate error
        IEnumerable<ModelError> allErrors = ModelState.Values.SelectMany(v => v.Errors);
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {            
            return View(model);
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {           
                    var checkboxPrograms = model.Programs.ToList();
               
                    _context.Entry(Letter).Property("Programs").CurrentValue = checkboxPrograms;

                    _context.Add(model);
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                   
                    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
              
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw ex;
            }
        }
      
    }
```

create.cshtml view:

```
@model Letter.Models.viewModel
    <form asp-action="Create" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="grid-x grid-padding-x">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            </div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-x grid-padding-x">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
               
                <input asp-for="@Model.Letter.Id" type="hidden" class="form-control" />         
            </div>          
    <div class="grid-x grid-padding-x">
                <label asp-for="@Model.Letter.Programs" class="control-label"></label><br/>
    
                            @{
               
                                for (int i = 0; i < Model.Programs.Count(); i++)
                                {
    
                                    <div class="form-check">
    
                                        @Model.Programs[i].ProgramText
                                        @Html.CheckBoxFor(r => Model.Programs[i].Selected)
    
                                        @Html.HiddenFor(h => @Model.Programs[i].ProgramValue)
                                        @Html.HiddenFor(h => @Model.Programs[i].ProgramText)
    
                                    </div>
    
                                }
    
                            }
                                     
    </div>
    <div> <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" /></div>
```

I got modelstate.valid is false because model.Letter is null. Please help! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out myself. The model retuns after removing Bind in Create method.
public async Task Create(viewModel model) {}